# SQL Server return multiple queries in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table

```
ID      TYPE        Text       ImagePath     Title    Date

 1      Text        Test        NULL          NULL     14/10/2013
 2      Image       NULL        /test/test    NULL     14/10/2013
 3      Title       NULL        NULL          Test     14/10/2013
 4      Text        Test2       NULL          NULL     20/12/2012
```

How can I retrieve ONLY the last 3 (sorted by date) records, 1 with type Text, 1 with type Image and 1 with type Title only? (Basically I only need the type and related field which is not NULL.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Are you looking for only the most recent record of each type?

Comment: @nycdan yes that is exactly what im looking for. Sorry for not being in title/description but did not know exactly how to word it.

Comment: When you have a column "type" and the 3 columns all are varchar, why don't you combine them in one column?

Comment: @fancyPants yes that actually makes more sense and would solve my problem. Thank you

Comment: So in trying to solve this, I just learned that you can't do an ORDER BY before Union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from restructuring your database as I said in the comment on your question, this should give you what you want (if I understood the question properly):

```
SELECT
TOP 1 
'Text' AS Type,
Text
FROM
your_table
ORDER BY Date DESC
UNION ALL
SELECT
TOP 1 
'ImagePath',
ImagePath
FROM
your_table
ORDER BY Date DESC
UNION ALL
SELECT
'Title', 
TOP 1 Title
FROM
your_table
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

You may have to put some parantheses here and there to make it work...

Answer (score 0):

One idea could be:

```
SELECT  * FROM table where TYPE = 'Text' OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY 
union
SELECT  * FROM table where TYPE = 'Image' OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY 
union
SELECT  * FROM table where TYPE = 'Title' OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Use UNION ALL when you don't need to eliminate duplicates - is this even compatible with MS Sql Server

Comment: Yes, we could use union all here, but there's no need because it won't return duplicate rows as long as the type betweens the select are always different ;-)

Comment: does this order properly to select the most recent?  Also, I agree with Charleh that this isn't SQL Server syntax.

Comment: You misunderstood him. Using UNION ALL is a performance tweak, as the Server doesn't need to look for duplicates. Also your answer is totally wrong. OP asked for "last 3".

Comment: Yes - avoid UNION because it's a performance penalty - especially for larger data sets when you don't need to eliminate dupes. My rule of thumb is UNION ALL unless you know why you are using UNION.

Comment: Living and learning ;-)  The question was really tricky, but you got it fancyPants.  Congrats ;-)